# Search two lists for regex match and pop if exists

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
list_one = ['aaa1a', 'bbb21ba', 'ccc4ba', 'qqq55ca']
list_two = ['eee21a', 'sws21ba', 'pop4ba', 'qqq55de']
```

There letters after the last digit represent an area; I can already find this using regex

```
regex = re.compile(r"[^[0-9]+$")
reg_list = []
for i in list_one:
    reg_list.append(regex.findall(i))
```

Which would give

```
reg_list = [u'a', u'ba', u'ba', u'ca']
```

I want to search list_two to check if any of its items match anything from my reg_list, and if so remove it from that list. So I would end up with

```
list_two = ['qqq55de']
```

as 'de' is the only location not in list_one. My current code is

```
for i in list_one:
    for j in list_two:
        find_location = regex.findall(j)
        if a == find_location:
            list_two.pop(j)
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Is there a better way of performing this?

Comment: On what line do you get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already got `reg_list`, you can now use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: re.findall(regex, x)[0] not in reg_list, list_two)
```

I don't like one-lining everything when it becomes unreadable. Just consider the most readable (and of course most efficient) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension as a shorter, more concise alternative:

```
import re
list_one = ['aaa1a', 'bbb21ba', 'ccc4ba', 'qqq55ca']
list_two = ['eee21a', 'sws21ba', 'pop4ba', 'qqq55de']
new_list_two = [i for i in list_two if any(re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+$', '', i) == re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+$', '', b) for b in list_one)]
```

Output:

```
['qqq55de']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify a list while iterating on it. But you can create a new one

```
import re

list_one = ['aaa1a', 'bbb21ba', 'ccc4ba', 'qqq55ca']
list_two = ['eee21a', 'sws21ba', 'pop4ba', 'qqq55de']

regex = re.compile(r"[^0-9]+$")
reg_list = []
for i in list_one:
    reg_list.append(regex.findall(i)[0])

list_two = [j for j in list_two if regex.findall(j)[0] not in reg_list]

print(list_two)
```

Result:

```
['qqq55de']
```